# Binding csv file outside virtual path to datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm developing a ASP.NET 4.5 application which reads a log file of another application which is in server My Documents folder.
It works well when I run in debug mode but not once deployed. 
Gives following error :

> 'C:\Users\Performance\My Folder\Log\' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.

I have given Network Service and IISUSER read/write access to this file.(*only this file and not folder*)

This my code :

```
     protected void lstArea_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          //create instance foe oledb connection class
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        //Your datasource Location path currently i placed csv file in server location 
        string dsource = lstArea.SelectedValue;
        //Put your datasource path in the connection string for example if you have csv files in C:\ directory change datasource= C:\
        string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + dsource + ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited';";

        try
        {
            con.ConnectionString = constr;
            //create instance for command object 
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            // set your file name in the below query
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from [wksplog.txt]";
            //Open Oledb Connection to read CSV file 
            con.Open();
            //Create one datatable to store data from CSV file
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader(), LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
            //Bind data in the Gridview
            gvMain.DataSource = dt;
            gvMain.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }   
    }
```

I'm passing the directory as C:\Users\Performance\My Folder\Log\

What is going wrong? BTW am using anonymous/ forms authentication. This machine is not in the domain.

Comment: Randeep, you need to give access to the Folder how else are you going to write and or get access to the file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user the application is running as needs read access to all parent folders of the log file otherwise you will receive an access violation.

Comment: That worked. But I hoped can only limit access to this file since I don't want to expose other files in same folder.